# How to print out dynamic items from array to the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am stuck in a logical problem.

I have an array where i am stacking items with `array.push()` where came up from a user's Input.
Problem is now:
How can i print these items to the DOM? ATM i am doing this,

```js
    function getInput(operator, description, value) {
      // SAVE IN INCOME IF "+" IS CHOOSEN (DEFAULT)
      if (addType.value == 'inc') {
        let op = incomeArr['operator'] = operator;
        let des = incomeArr['description'] = description;
        let val = incomeArr['value'] = value;
        incomeArr.push([op, des, val]);

        return incomeArr;
      }
    }
```

Creating a associative array in the `getInput();`
First attempt to print this data into the DOM looked like this:

```js
function printToDOM(item) {
  // every function call should run this once to update the UI
  const incomeList = document.querySelector('.income__list');
  const expenseList = document.querySelector('.expenses__list');

  let incomeItemSpan = `<span> ${item.description}: ${item.value} </span></br>`;
  let expenseItemSpan = `<span> ${item.description}: ${item.value} </span> </br>`;


  for (var i = 0; i < expenseArr.length; i++) {
      incomeItemSpan;
      incomeList.append(incomeItemSpan);
    }
}
```

My problem here is that my forLoop index condition is messing up because of the "everytime function call" the value which is printed out will be printed twice in the next function call of this. the index start again at 0 and even with a out of function loop counter this will not work.

[![gave-input][1]][1]

So the next attempt was:

```js
function printToDOM(item) {
  // every function call should run this once to update the UI
  const incomeList = document.querySelector('.income__list');
  const expenseList = document.querySelector('.expenses__list');

  let incomeItemSpan = `<span> ${item.description}: ${item.value} </span></br>`;
  let expenseItemSpan = `<span> ${item.description}: ${item.value} </span> </br>`;

  incomeArr.forEach(() => {
    incomeList.innerHTML = incomeItemSpan;
  });
}
```

i tried it with a forEach and the problem here is, i have absolutely no idea how to print out the `incomeItemSpan` without a innerHTML. I want a list of items in the DOM which are stacked from top down, every line is a new item from the array like i would use `item.append()`, but HTML wont work in a append().

How can i do this?

```js
/* TODO:
  - Add Eventlistener for Submit a +/- Value
  - if + {add 1. into INCOME section} + Set INCOME in header to the amount
  of all incomes added
  if - {same like if+ just for -}
  - create a update DOM function to update the visualisation of the calculations
  - INCOME AND EXPENSES should be a Array
  - add a prototype function to remove entrys from INCOME and EXPENSES, use
  indexOf to get the index item and remove with array.splice().
  - calc every expense  with INCOME to get a % value of how much this entry is
  % related to the max INCOME
*/

// VARS:
let addType = document.querySelector('.add__type');
let description = document.querySelector('.add__description');
let addValue = document.querySelector('.add__value');
let incomeArr = [];
let expenseArr = [];


// EVENTLISTENER Constructor:
function EventListner(selector, listner, fnt) {
  this.selector = selector;
  this.listner = listner;
  this.fnt = fnt;
  document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener(listner, fnt);
};

// getInput VALUES FROM USER Constructor:
function getInput(operator, description, value) {
  // SAVE IN INCOME IF "+" IS CHOOSEN (DEFAULT)
  if (addType.value == 'inc') {
    let op = incomeArr['operator'] = operator;
    let des = incomeArr['description'] = description;
    let val = incomeArr['value'] = value;
    incomeArr.push([op, des, val]);

    // TODO: WHAT AFTER SAVING?
    return incomeArr;
  }
  // SAVE IN EXPENSE IF "-" IS CHOOSEN
  if (addType.value == 'exp') {
    let op = expenseArr['operator'] = operator;
    let des = expenseArr['description'] = description;
    let val = expenseArr['value'] = value;
    expenseArr.push([op, des, val]);

    // TODO: WHAT AFTER SAVING?
    return expenseArr;
  }

};

// STUCK AS FUCK!

function printToDOM(item) {
  // every function call should run this once to update the UI
  const incomeList = document.querySelector('.income__list');
  const expenseList = document.querySelector('.expenses__list');

  let incomeItemSpan = `<span> ${item.description}: ${item.value} </span></br>`;
  let expenseItemSpan = `<span> ${item.description}: ${item.value} </span> </br>`;

  incomeArr.forEach(() => {
    incomeList.innerHTML = incomeItemSpan;
  });

  // for (var i = 0; i < incomeArr.length; i++) {
  //   console.log([i]);
  //   incomeItemSpan;
  //   incomeList.append(incomeItemSpan);
  // }

  // console.log(incomeItemSpan);
  //

  // incomeList.append(expenseArr);
  // incomeArr.toString();
  // expenseArr.toString();
  // incomeList.innerHTML = incomeItemSpan;


};




const main = (function() {
  // EVENTLISTENERS
  const clickListener = new EventListner('.add__btn', 'click', () => {
    if (description.value == '' || addValue.value == '') {
      // MAKE SURE DESCRIPTION AND VALUE IS NOT EMPTY
      alert('description and value can\'t be empty');
      return;
    }
    getInput(addType.value, description.value, addValue.value);
  });


  const enterKeyListener = new EventListner('.add__value', 'keypress', (e) => {
    let testArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
      testArray[i] = [i];
      console.log(testArray[i]);
    }
    testArray.push('item');

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      if (description.value == '' || addValue.value == '') {
        // MAKE SURE DESCRIPTION AND VALUE IS NOT EMPTY
        alert('description and value can\'t be empty');
        return;
      }
      // ON ENTER SAVE VALUES IN AN ARRAY
      // IF PLUS INTO incomeArr, ON MINUS INTO expenseArr
      // getInput(addType.value, description.value, addValue.value);
      printToDOM(getInput(addType.value, description.value, addValue.value));
    }
  });


}());

//
```

```css
/**********************************************
*** GENERAL
**********************************************/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

body {
    color: #555;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.right { float: right; }
.red { color: #FF5049 !important; }
.red-focus:focus { border: 1px solid #FF5049 !important; }

/**********************************************
*** TOP PART
**********************************************/

.top {
    height: 40vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)), url(back.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
}

.budget {
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #fff;
}

.budget__title {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.budget__value {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 46px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.budget__income,
.budget__expenses {
    padding: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.budget__income {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #28B9B5;
}

.budget__expenses {
    background-color: #FF5049;
}

.budget__income--text,
.budget__expenses--text {
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #444;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.budget__income--value,
.budget__expenses--value {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    float: left;
}

.budget__income--percentage,
.budget__expenses--percentage {
    float: left;
    width: 34px;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 3px 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.budget__expenses--percentage {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
}


/**********************************************
*** BOTTOM PART
**********************************************/

/***** FORM *****/
.add {
    padding: 14px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.add__container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.add__type {
    width: 55px;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    height: 44px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-weight: 300;
    transition: border 0.3s;
}

.add__description,
.add__value {
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: border 0.3s;
}

.add__description { width: 400px;}
.add__value { width: 100px;}

.add__btn {
    font-size: 35px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #28B9B5;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.add__btn:active { transform: translateY(2px); }

.add__type:focus,
.add__description:focus,
.add__value:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #28B9B5;
}

.add__btn:focus { outline: none; }

/***** LISTS *****/
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 60px auto;
}

.income {
    float: left;
    width: 475px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.expenses {
    float: left;
    width: 475px;
}

h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.icome__title { color: #28B9B5; }
.expenses__title { color: #FF5049; }

.item {
    padding: 13px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.item:first-child { border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7; }
.item:nth-child(even) { background-color: #f7f7f7; }

.item__description {
    float: left;
}

.item__value {
    float: left;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.item__percentage {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    font-size: 11px;
    background-color: #FFDAD9;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}

.income .item__value,
.income .item__delete--btn {
    color: #28B9B5;
}

.expenses .item__value,
.expenses .item__percentage,
.expenses .item__delete--btn {
    color: #FF5049;
}


.item__delete {
    float: left;
}

.item__delete--btn {
    font-size: 22px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1;
    display: none;
}

.item__delete--btn:focus { outline: none; }
.item__delete--btn:active { transform: translateY(2px); }

.item:hover .item__delete--btn { display: block; }
.item:hover .item__value { transform: translateX(-20px); }
.item:hover .item__percentage { transform: translateX(-20px); }


.unpaid {
    background-color: #FFDAD9 !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FF5049;

}

.unpaid .item__percentage { box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }
.unpaid:hover .item__description { font-weight: 900; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Budgety</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="top">
    <div class="budget">
      <div class="budget__title">
        Available Budget in <span class="budget__title--month">%Month%</span>:
      </div>

      <div class="budget__value">+ 0</div>

      <div class="budget__income clearfix">
        <div class="budget__income--text">Income</div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="budget__income--value">+ 0</div>
          <div class="budget__income--percentage">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="budget__expenses clearfix">
        <div class="budget__expenses--text">Expenses</div>
        <div class="right clearfix">
          <div class="budget__expenses--value">- 0</div>
          <div class="budget__expenses--percentage">0%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="add">
      <div class="add__container">
        <select class="add__type">
          <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
          <option value="exp">-</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="add__description" placeholder="Add description">
        <input type="number" class="add__value" placeholder="Value">
        <button class="add__btn"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="income">
        <h2 class="icome__title">Income</h2>

        <div class="income__list">


                        <!-- <div class="item clearfix" id="income-0">
                            <div class="item__description"></div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value"></div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Sold car</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 1,500.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> -->


        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="expenses">
        <h2 class="expenses__title">Expenses</h2>

        <div class="expenses__list">

          <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Apartment rent</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 900.00</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">21%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Grocery shopping</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 435.28</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">10%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please always include all the relevant code so we can see a running example of what you results are and provide a working example. Add the relevant HTML please.

Comment: By the way. `getInput()` doesn't create an associative array - it creates a multi-dimensional array. Associative arrays in JavaScript are objects, where the keys and values are associated. You aren't using that approach.

Comment: @ScottMarcus isnt this a key: value for you? Key is `incomeArr['description'] and value is `description`

Comment: If `incomeArr` is an object, then yes. But if `incomeArr` is an Array, then no because Arrays don't have string indexers like `description`. Your code seems to try to use `incomeArr` as both an Array (with the use of the `.push()` method call that inserts a new Array item with no associated key [because Arrays don't have keys]) and an object (by passing string keys). You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Please always include your relevant code in your question, not at a 3rd party link, which can die over time. Just insert your code into a code snippet as I've done for you and it's just like a Fiddle.

Comment: @Deniz This isn't PHP, if you use array.forEach, you will only iterate through numeric keys.

Comment: @Akxe `.forEach()` will iterate through the ***indexes*** of the Array. Arrays do not have keys, objects do. When the OP writes `incomArr["description"]` he is not adding an item to the Array, he is creating an new property on that instance of the Array object. That property will not be enumerated with `.forEach()`.

Comment: See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/objd016y/5/) for a demonstration of what you are actually doing with your Arrays. You aren't using them as associative (Arrays don't do that). You are simply adding properties that aren't enumerable with the Array API.

Comment: @ScottMarcus under the hood, array and object are the same. You can prove it using `Object.keys(arr)`. What array have is computed property `length` and `Symbol.iterator`, that will cause that you can use it in `for of` loops.

Comment: @akxe No, not quite. All objects derive frim Object, but that does not make an Array and an Object the same thing. I’m not going to debate the fundamentals of OOP. Arrays have indexes, which are numbers and Objects have keys, which are strings. They are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Is that exactly what you're looking for?

```js
const arr = new Array();

function addList() {
  const el = document.querySelector("input[name=user]")
  const val = el.value
  arr.push(val);
  el.value = null;

  return false;
}

function showList() {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const listElement = document.createElement("li");
    listElement.textContent = arr[i]
    document.body.appendChild(listElement);
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return addList()">
  <input type="text" name="user">
  <button>Add list item</button>
</form><br>

<button class="showList" onclick="showList()">Show list</button>
    
<ul class="list"></ul>
```

Comment: close to. i want the `showList` be executed on every new input. Means, once you click btn "Add list item" the `showList` function should executed BUT, it should't print out every index again, just the latest new item and update the list. You see the problem when you add a few items and press the btn twice. all the items will get added again from the beginning.

Comment: i guess you want to have unique elements on the list.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a list of items, create a ordered/unordered list then append each item to this list in forEach and finally set the html to ordered//unordered list.
Example:

```
var ol=$('<ol></ol>');
incomeArr.forEach(() =>  {
  ol.append($('<li></li>').text(`${item.description}: ${item.value}`));
});

$('#display').html(ol);
```